# Jenkins job automatically building all SVN branches available

Tags: java, svn, jenkins

is there a possibility to Setup a Job which builds all available branches automatically?

```
<svn-repo>/branches/*
```

Further it should ignore one Folder which is:

```
<svn-repo>/branches/closed
```

It's a time-triggered Job.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure jobs for each branch, then define the periodicity